# Kotlin Gradle adding --add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle, java-time

In my app I made a couple features having to do with the `Instant` and `Date` features that I get an error message:

```
Unable to make field private final long java.time.Instant.seconds accessible: 
module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @2e351f37
```

One of these messages is coming from a gson serialization attempt:

```kotlin
// filter object being sent to external API
val startTime: Instant, // internal app functions handles stuff using `Instant` 
val startDate: Date = Date.from(startTime) // external API works with Date serialization

class DateSerializer: JsonSerializer<Date> {
   override fun serialize(src: Date?, typeOfSrc: Type?, context: JsonSerializationContext?): JsonElement {
      return JsonPrimitive(src?.time)
   }
}
```

I did a search and found I could add the following to my IntelliJ Idea VM options that would allow this:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED
```

In my `build.gradle.kts` file I have the following which worked to debug my tests:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
   useJUnitPlatform()
   jvmArgs("--add-opens", "java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED")
}
```

In IntelliJ I can add those to my VM Options in my Run/Debug configurations and it works in the app.

My question is how could I add these options within the gradle file so that whenever the app is started, it knows to apply these settings? Such as when I click "run", "debug" or later on build it into a jar file and officially deploy it.

I tried to do it with the below setting but that did literally nothing:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<JavaExec> {
   jvmArgs("--add-opens", "java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED")
}
```

Comment: What you tried with `withType<JavaExec>` should work when running/debugging your project via Gradle. As for after deployment, that depends. If your JAR is an executable JAR file, then you can add an `Add-Opens` to the manifest. However, if your JAR is a library, then I don't believe there's anything you can do except tell consumers they have to manually add `--add-opens`. That all said, this could be an XY problem; why do you need to open the `java.time` package anyway?

Comment: In response to your edit: I think `--add-opens` is the wrong solution. I suggest creating an adapter for `Instant` and registering it. If you need adapters for more `java.time` classes than just `Instant`, I believe there are a few libraries out there that provide them for you.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks, I used your advice above to just create an Instant adapter: `override fun serialize(src: Instant?, typeOfSrc: Type?, context: JsonSerializationContext?): JsonElement { return JsonPrimitive(src?.toEpochMilli()) }` which works just as well and doesn't require the --adds-opens.